# web scraping checking if a word is in a string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the styles of the bags from their product name (for example, "Tote" from "Platinum Faux Patent Leather Tote"). Here's my code:

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    saksurl="http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/Handbags/shop/_/N-52jzot/Ne-  6lvnb5?FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374306622829"
    html = urlopen(saksurl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser")  
    for product in bsObj.select("#product-container [id^=product-]"):
      Style="None"

      Name=product.find("p",{"class":"product-description"}).get_text()


     print(Name)

     if Name.find("Tote"):
       Style="Tote"
     else:
       Style="None"
     print(Style)
```

While it should be giving me None for bags that are not Totes and Tote for bags that are Totes, it's giving me Totes for all the bags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
 if "Tote" in Name:
     ...
```

Instead of `str.find`. `str.find` will return the index if found or it will return `-1`. Either way, any number that isn't 0 will evaluate to `True` and this is where you're getting your error from.